# Filter datas of list of arrays using search form

Tags: php, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have list of arrays which all my products are listed. Sample array:

```
$products = array();

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 1','description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 
                    'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 1', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p1.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/1/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 2','description' => 'Donec eleifend quam neque, ut mollis massa aliquet id.',
                    'location' => 'B city', 'type' => 'Type 1', 'status' => 'under', 'tags'=>'show-homepage', 'page_url'=>'p2.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/2/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 3','description' => 'Nam non tristique mi.',
                    'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 3', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p3.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/3/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 4','description' => 'Vestibulum accumsan dolor id orci gravida viverra.',
                    'location' => 'C city', 'type' => 'Type 2', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p4.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/4/prod-image.jpg');
```

What I want to achieve is to show all products that was filtered using search form. Similar to SQL query condition `WHERE location = $_GET['location'] AND type = $_GET['type'] AND status = $_GET['status']`. Consider that when value selected is `Any` (Ex. location or status = any) it will filter only the `type` of product regardless of the locations and status or vice versa..

This is my html form:

```
<form name="search-form" method="GET">

            <div class="searchform-title">Location</div> 
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <select name="location" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
                 <option value='Any' selected>Any</option>
                 <option value='A city'>A city</option>
                 <option value='B City'>B City</option>
                 <option value='C city'>C city</option>
                 <option value='D city'>D city</option>
                 <option value='L city'>L city</option>
                 <option value='M city'>M city</option> 
                 <option value='T city'>T city</option>
             </select>
             </div>

            <div class="searchform-title">Type</div> 
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <select name="type" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
                 <option value='Any' selected>Any</option>
                 <option value='Type 1'>Type 1</option>
                 <option value='Type 2'>Type 2</option>
                 <option value='Type 3'>Type 3</option>
                 <option value='Type 4'>Type 4</option>
             </select>
             </div>

              <div class="searchform-title">Status</div> 
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <select name="status" style="width:100%; padding:5px">
                 <option value='Any' selected>Any</option>
                 <option value='New'>New</option>
                 <option value='Old'>Old</option>
                 <option value='Under'>Under</option>
             </select>
             </div>

            <input class="proj-search-btn" type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
        </form>
```

What I have tried so far is using a function but it only get the location of the product.
Here is the sample function code. [See sample code](http://ideone.com/Ay3Iwm)

Is there a better way to search items in list of arrays using a search form? And having 3 selected value(query) to search?

Comment: One way would be to recall your search function using the results of the previous call and the new attribute.

Comment: @MasterDJon how can I add new attribute to the first(s) filtered array?

Comment: `$productsFiltered = search($products, 'firstKey', 'firstValue'); $productsFiltered = search($productsFiltered, 'secondKey', 'secondValue);`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to use `array_filter`.

```
<?php

$products = array();

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 1','description' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 1', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p1.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/1/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 2','description' => 'Donec eleifend quam neque, ut mollis massa aliquet id.', 'location' => 'B city', 'type' => 'Type 1', 'status' => 'under', 'tags'=>'show-homepage', 'page_url'=>'p2.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/2/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 3','description' => 'Nam non tristique mi.', 'location' => 'A city', 'type' => 'Type 3', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p3.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/3/prod-image.jpg');

$products[] = array('name'=> 'Product 4','description' => 'Vestibulum accumsan dolor id orci gravida viverra.', 'location' => 'C city', 'type' => 'Type 2', 'status' => 'new', 'tags'=>'', 'page_url'=>'p4.html', 'image'=>'products/assets/images/4/prod-image.jpg');

function search($products, $criteria) {
    return array_filter($products, function($product) use ($criteria) {
        return array_reduce(array_keys($criteria), function($carry, $key) use ($product, $criteria) {
            return $carry && ($product[$key]===$criteria[$key]);
        }, true);
    });
}

$r = search($products, array('location'=>'A city', 'type'=>'Type 3'));
// if you don't care about keys of the array, you can skip sort
sort($r);

var_dump($r);
```

result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Product 3"
    ["description"]=>
    string(21) "Nam non tristique mi."
    ["location"]=>
    string(6) "A city"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "Type 3"
    ["status"]=>
    string(3) "new"
    ["tags"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["page_url"]=>
    string(7) "p3.html"
    ["image"]=>
    string(39) "products/assets/images/3/prod-image.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: using your solution, how can I show all filtered items using search form? On my sample I have 3 value to search namely: location, type and the status of the product?

Comment: I got no data in array output : `array(0) { }`

Comment: Also the function don't work when the first or 2nd or 3rd selected value is empty.

Comment: omg.. just filter it out.. "use the power, Luke" (c), just call the function with non-empty values